# Proving $\lim_{x\to c}x^3=c^3$ for any $c\in\mathbb R$ using $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits, epsilon-delta

> $\lim_{x\to 3}x^3=c^3$ for any $c\in\mathbb R$

Let $\epsilon>0$. Then
$$|x^3-c^3|=|x-c||x^2+xc+c^2|.$$

Let $\delta=\min\{1,\epsilon/x^2+xc+c^2\}$.
Then if $0<|x-c|<\delta$ and therefore since $|x-c|<\epsilon/(x^2+xc+c^2)$,
$$|x^3-c^3|=|x-c||x^2+xc+c^2|<ε.$$

Does this make sense or are the steps done in the right way?

Comment: You can't define $\delta$ in terms of $x$, because you don't know $x$ yet - you are asserting it is true for *all* $x$ in the range.

Comment: No, this is wrong. $\delta$ must be independent of $x$

Comment: $\lim_{x \to 3} x^3 = 27$

Comment: you mean $\lim_{x \to c} x^3 = c^3?$

Comment: From your question history, it appears you have never once accepted an answer. If mine or Aaron's answer was satisfactory to you, then you really should accept one of them (whichever one you found more helpful). This lets others on MSE know you are satisfied with an answer, gives the answerer due acknowledgment, etc. I'd suggest going back through your other questions and accepting answers that you found satisfactory (you only have $10$ questions so this should be manageable). Just a tip.

Comment: @abel I corrected the title. I think it is pretty clear what OP meant given the displayed work.

Comment: @MagicMan, good work. some op's may not know how mse works. i wish there was some place they can learn the basic etiquette of how this site works and have some courtesy to the people taking time to answer their questions.

Comment: @MagicMan click the check-mark next to the question.

Comment: if you hover the mouse around the uparrow to the left of the answer, it lets you accept an answer. you can change your mind if you find a better answer later on.

Comment: @AxelFoley Like Omnomnomnom said, you click the check mark underneath the down arrow--see it?

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Surely you meant OP?

Comment: @abel I agree. That would be nice! I usually don't say anything, but it bothers me when someone has *zero* accepted answers. That is, like you say, bad etiquette.

Comment: @MagicMan yes i got it thanks

Comment: @AxelFoley Glad it helped! And don't forget about your other 9 questions...wouldn't take long to tick off a few check marks if the answers really did answer your question. :)

Comment: @MagicMan oops!

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Haha no worries. I was pretty certain you didn't mean me :p oddly enough, OP accepted Aaron's answer after having accepted mine. Hey, to each his own--I'm just glad OP knows how to accept questions. Although...zero votes cast. :/ Hopefully that becomes clear. There really should be an "etiquette" guide.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|x^3-c^3|<\epsilon$. Now,
$$
|x^3-c^3| = |x-c||x^2+xc+c^2|.
$$
If $|x-c|<1$, then we have that $-1<x-c<1$ or simply $c-1<x<c+1$ so that
$$
x^2+xc+c^2<(c+1)^2+(c+1)(c)+c^2=(c^2+2c+1)+(c^2+c)+c^2=3c^2+3c+1,
$$
and so
$$
|x^3-c^3| = |x-c||x^2+xc+c^2|<(3c^2+3c+1)|x-c|.
$$
So if we take $\delta=\min\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3c^2+3c+1}\right\}$, then $0<|x-c|<\delta$ implies that
$$
|x^3-c^3|=|x-c||x^2+xc+c^2|<\frac{\epsilon}{3c^2+3c+1}\cdot(3c^2+3c+1)=\epsilon.
$$
Thus, by the definition of a limit, we have that
$$
\lim_{x\to c}x^3=c^3. \blacksquare
$$

Comment: thanks a lot this looks right and very hepful n clear

Comment: $xc$ is not $ < c(c+1) \; \; if \; \;c < 0$

Comment: I don't see how this is correct. Clearly you can't conclude $f(x)<f(c+1)$ if $x<c+1$ unless $f$ in a monotonically increasing function in $[x,c+1]$ and here $f(t)=t^2+ct+c^2$ which is not monotonically increasing in $[x,c+1]$ because $x,c \in \Bbb{R}$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** $\delta$ should not be depending of $x$.

Consider $c > 0$ then

$$ c - 1 < x < c+ 1 \implies |x| < c + 1  $$

Then $$\begin{align}|x^3 - c^3| &= |x - c| |x^2 + xc  +c^2| \\&\leq |x-c|\bigg(|c+1|^2 + |c+1||c| + + |c|^2\bigg) \\&=|x-c|\bigg[|c+1|(|c + 1| + |c|) + |c|^2\bigg]\end{align} $$

Take $$\delta = \min \Bigg\{1, \frac{\epsilon}{|c+1|(|c + 1| + |c|) + |c|^2}\Bigg\}$$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $\varepsilon>0$. The inequality
$$
|x^3-c^3|<\varepsilon
$$
becomes
$$
c^3-\varepsilon<x^3<c^3+\varepsilon
$$
or
$$
\sqrt[3]{c^3-\varepsilon}<x<\sqrt[3]{c^3+\varepsilon}
$$
or also
$$
\sqrt[3]{c^3-\varepsilon}-c<x-c<\sqrt[3]{c^3+\varepsilon}-c
$$
Take
$$
\delta=\min\{c-\sqrt[3]{c^3-\varepsilon},\sqrt[3]{c^3+\varepsilon}-c\}
$$
after noting that
$$
c-\sqrt[3]{c^3-\varepsilon}>0
$$
and
$$
\sqrt[3]{c^3+\varepsilon}-c>0
$$

Answer (score 0):

Given $\epsilon>0$, we need $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-c|<\delta$, then $|x^3-c^3|<\epsilon$.

Now,
$
|x^3-c^3| = |x-c||x^2+cx+c^2|
$

If $|x-c|<1$, then
$||x|-|c|| \leq |x-c|<1$

i.e. $||x|-|c||<1 \implies -1<|x|-|c|<1 \implies |x|<|c|+1$
so that
$$
|x^2+cx+c^2|\leq |x|^2+|c||x|+|c|^2 < (|c|+1)^2+|c|(|c|+1)+|c|^2=3|c|^2+3|c|+1,
$$
and so
$$
|x^3-c^3| = |x-c||x^2+cx+c^2|<(3|c|^2+3|c|+1)|x-c|.
$$
Therefore, for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists a $\delta=\inf\left\{1,\frac{\epsilon}{3|c|^2+3|c|+1}\right\}>0$, such that if $ 0<|x-c|<\delta$ then

$\begin{align} |x^3-c^3|&=|x-c||x^2+cx+c^2|\\
&<\frac{\epsilon}{3|c|^2+3|c|+1}\cdot(3|c|^2+3|c|+1)\\
&=\epsilon \end{align}
$

Thus, by the definition of limit of a function
$$
\lim_{x\to c}x^3=c^3.
$$